# How to create Excel Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I normally have no issues creating **simple** conditional formatting formulas in Excel.
But the following formula works fine in a normal cell but not when used as a conditional formatting formula. What can be the problem?

```
 =AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN($B:$B)))="";INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN($B:$B)))<>"")
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The indirection seems unnecessary. Have you tried this?

```
=AND($B2="";$B1<>"")
```

Comment: In a normal cell that would work - but not in a conditional formatting formula I think?

Comment: @Phiplex Not in this particular case, since I don't have Excel on my personal PC, but at work I have used similar formulae for formatting on several occasions.